# Unable to change the boot order of Ubuntu 16.04 dual installed with Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10, grub-efi, boot-order

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 with Windows 10. No matter what I do, it always boots up Windows first. I have tried four ways:

- Changed boot order using `sudo efibootmgr -o` command on Ubuntu.
- Used `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` to
  change the windows boot file.
- Used [EasyUEFI](http://easyuefi.com/) on windows to change
  the File Path of the windows boot manager to both
  `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` and `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`.
- Again used [EasyUEFI](http://easyuefi.com/) to change the order of different boot profiles.

Disappointingly, every boot process starts directly booting the windows. On checking the boot order and its settings I find that there are two windows boot profiles. One of these two always stay at the top, and is uneditable by every means that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a GUI for stuff I barely understand. So, I use grub-customizer for this exact reason. It is confirmed working for me on 16.04,02 and 16.10. It allows you to set the boot order and default boots from a convenient GUI.

If you want to try it out, you can add the ppa which is `ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer`

Then;

```
$sudo apt-get update
```

and finally

```
$ sudo apt-get grub-customizer
```

It should show up in your tools menu somewhere.

Comment: GRUB Customizer is unlikely to work in this case, since it appears that GRUB isn't launching at all. This is a known problem on some buggy EFIs.